# How to withdraw Stellar lumens into USD?

Tags: stellar-core

I was one of the (lucky?) people to have signed up for Stellar and now have about 6000 lumens, but I have no clue how to convert it into USD i.e withdraw .

Also wondering is there a fixed rate of conversion for XLM or just depends on the buyer?

Answer (score 4):

Use of of the [exchanges](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/stellar/#markets).

When it comes to actual withdrawal process it looks like this:

- After registering an account in the exchange, go to Deposit section.
- You will be presented a Stellar address and memo. Use your wallet to send a payment to that address and add memo to your transaction.
- **Always** start by sending a small amount first (1-2 USD worth of lumens?). If the initial transfer is successful, send the rest of money (in batches or full sum - it depends how much you can afford to lose in case of errors). Usually there are no deposit fees but please check your exchange pricing.
- Once your lumens are at the exchange account you should see them in your account Balance section.
- Usually you have two options when it comes to exchanging lumens from/to other currency:

  - You can create a *market order* - it means that you will sell lumens consuming the best buy orders in the order book.
  - You can create a sell offer at a given price - it means that lumens will be sold at the price selected by you but it will only happen if someone else is willing to buy lumens at this price. It's possible it will never happen if the price is too high.
- The last step is to withdraw USD to your bank account - this can be done in Withdrawal section in your exchange.